# Max date between two dates teradata

Tags: sqlite, date, sas, max, teradata

I am running the following proc sql to pull out the max date.

```
Proc sql;
   Connect to TERADATA (login details);
   Create table dates as 
   Select * from connection to TERADATA
  ( select max (date1,'2011-12-31') from table1
);
Quit;

Error:
Syntax error: expected something between the word      'date1' and ','
```

Can someone help me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most flavors of SQL, the `max` function is an aggregation function, which only takes one argument and then takes the column (or whatever is passed to it) and chooses the maximum value from that column.

SAS is different in that it overloads `max` to also work as a row-level function.

To do this you could do:

```
Proc sql;
   Connect to TERADATA (login details);
   Create table dates as 
   Select max(date1,'2011-12-31') from connection to TERADATA
  ( select date1 from table1
);
Quit;
```

Which pulls it out of the teradata and into SAS where it's legal to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in-database (push down optimization) with Teradata if you use the GREATEST function and cast the dates to INTEGER:

```
Proc sql;
   Connect to TERADATA (login details);
   Create table dates as 
   Select * from connection to TERADATA
  ( select GREATEST (CAST(date1 AS INTEGER), CAST(CAST('2011-12-31' AS DATE) AS INTEGER)) from table1
);
Quit;
```

**Note:** I double casted the second parameter to be on the safe side, even though it is being passed to Teradata in an implicit ANSI date format. If your date is nullable in the table (date1), there may be some obstacles with COALESCE.